# Bluetooth MIDI in OS X Mavericks?

Tags: bluetooth, midi

I just received a new wireless controller (Livid Minim) that works over Bluetooth MIDI.  It works fine with my iOS devices, but won't connect to my Mac at all.  I'm using a 2011 iMac running OSX Mavericks and will not be upgrading (A previous attempt to upgrade to Yosemite was disastrous and lost my entire system, had to restore from a complete disk image I took before the upgrade)

Is it possible to use Bluetooth MIDI devices in Mavericks?  Everything I read only refers to Yosemite or greater, but I see nothing that actually states it cannot function on Mavericks.  Would appreciate any definitive answer on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bluetooth MIDI in Yosemite (and up) Only

You cannot use Bluetooth MIDI in OS X Mavericks as it is not supported.  Bluetooth MIDI was implemented in Yosemite.  For more info, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1831/_index.html

> but I see nothing that actually states it cannot function on Mavericks.

It is very unlikely that you are going to see a statement from Apple stating that an OS three versions back specifically doesn't support a feature that was introduced in an OS that one version back.  **Features that are listed are what's supported, not listed as to what's not.**

Comment: Thanks, however I don't think it's at all unusual to find some discussion, somewhere, regarding a particular feature not being supported in a very popular version of the OS.  I could find nothing of the sort.  I also was not asking about Apple-specific support, but support in general.  In other words, perhaps there is some 3rd party solution to enable Bluetooth MIDI on Mavericks.  Maybe this is not possible, but that's why I came here to inquire.  Bluetooth MIDI is not an Apple-exclusive technology as far as I'm aware.

Comment: That type of support has to be built into the core bluetooth framework (meaning Apple) and cannot be added by 3rd party developers.  While it's not exclusive to Apple, Apple has to be the one to allow BT to "talk" to MIDI.  Secondly, it is highly unlikely that a 3rd party is going to develop it when Apple is going to make it available in Yosemite.  All the dev has to say is "upgrade to Yosemite" and they are done.  There is literally no incentive for them to create support for Mavericks.

Comment: OK, makes sense I guess.  But MIDI over BT has existed prior to Yosemite for quite some time, via a dongle.  This is a part of why I asked the question, it seemed that it was perfectly feasible to be added by a 3rd party rather than only by Apple.

Comment: That's just it, there was a "dongle."  The BT to MIDI "bridge" (lack of a better word)  was in the dongle, not in the OS.  As far as the OS was concerned, it was a *physical* MIDI device and had no idea that the MIDI signaling was coming over a BT connection.